# Whole website crashes when I upload a file

Tags: php, html, file-upload, crash

When I upload a file using an HTML form, as soon as I hit the "upload" button, the whole site crashes. I can't see the website for about 40 minutes but the FTP server is still available.

I don't understand why this is happening. Yesterday it worked fine and today it doesn't. Nothing was changed.

I use a simple form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="csvupload.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
Upload File: <input name="csv" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
 </form>
```

Comment: What sort of server do you have - shared, VPS, dedicated, cloud? Can you reach the server from a different browser on the same machine? How about a browser on a different device entirely (e.g. your mobile phone)? Does clearing your cookies on your primary browser make the server respond again?

Comment: @racecarjonathan it's a linux server from godaddy.com. on other devices, the website will also not work after i pushed the "upload" button. as i said, yesterday it all worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem...as i worked on my code, i made a copy & past failure so a for loop was in a infinite loop. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

how's your php error catching for the file upload?
I find code like this can be informative in these crash situations.

```
$file=$_FILES['file'];
        if (isset($_FILES['file'])==true){
            if ($file["error"] > 0)
            {
                $errors_array = array(  0=>"There is no error, the file uploaded with success", 
                    1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive!", 
                    2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive",
                    3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
                    4=>"No file was uploaded",
                    5=>"Unknown Error",
                    6=>"Missing temporary folder"
                );
                $error=$file["error"];

            }
    }
```

keeps the move_uploaded_file from being executed.